# Unit.INSTANCE vs Unit? Unit compiles but has IDE error, Unit.INSTANCE doesn't compile but no IDE error

Tags: kotlin

This definitely seems like a bug or configuration issue. Though red squiggly lines appear, this code below actually **compiles**.

[image]

When I change it to `Single.just(Unit.INSTANCE)`, it **doesn't compile** with compilation error `Unresolved reference: INSTANCE`, but no IDE warnings/ errors are shown:

[image]

For your information, this is what Unit looks like for me:
[image]

Has anyone faced this, and what is the best way to correct this?

Comment: Rebuild, close, reopen?

Comment: Looks like your IDE is confused into seeing Unit as a Java class rather than a Kotlin class, but your compiler is not. Not sure what could cause that.

Comment: Unit definitely should work, works on my local machine. You can also try clearing your cache. Can you share the full file as a text, or at least show your imports.

Comment: I've tried invaliding caches and restarting Android Studio, and restarting the mac, it still has the same issue unfortunately

Comment: It happens even in a scratch file for me, without importing anything else, setting the classpath to `no module`, though in the scratch file, it doesn't even run: it provides the compile error as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I am actually using Android Studio Arctic Fox Canary 8, so I will downgrade. Didn't think of trying that yet...